# Save checkbox values problems with sharedpreference

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I have trouble with this line:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

The problem I am having is that `(this)` has a red line. But the rest of the code is ok. What can be the problem here?
Here is the rest of the code:

```
public static class ShowDataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final CheckedTextView image_title;
    private final CheckBox chk;




    public ShowDataViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        image_title = (CheckedTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fetch_image_title);
        chk = (CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences();
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        if (preferences.contains("checked") && preferences.getBoolean("checked", false) == true){
            chk.setChecked(true);
        }else{
            chk.setChecked(false);
        }

        chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (chk.isChecked()){
                    editor.putBoolean("checked", true);
                    editor.apply();
                }else{
                    editor.putBoolean("checked", false);
                    editor.apply();
                }
            }
        });



    }

    private void Image_Title(String title) {
        image_title.setText(title);


    }
```

This class is inside my MainActivity.

Comment: What class is that code found? Activity, Fragment or what?

Comment: I have added the rest of the code. But it is inside my Activity.

Comment: I think I got it to work, but now, when I check one item it checks some others to. And when I refresh my list it checks all of my items. And if I uncheck one item and refresh my list it uncheck all of my items. So in a way the value is saved.

Comment: I know Alex thats is the issue or renewing views, its a late reply but if you still have some problems there let me know.